# App freezes when trying to pass a function in SetParams React-Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, use-effect, usecallback

I am trying to use setParams to pass a function to handle a button click in my navigationOptions but my app freezes instead. Here is my code and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
const handleVisibility = useCallback(()=>{
         setMenuVisible(!menuVisible)
 },[menuVisible])

 useEffect(()=>{
   props.navigation.setParams({
      visibility:handleVisibility
   })
 },[handleVisibility])
```

Comment: react-navigation version?

Comment: `setParams` is expected to be a store of `key : values` and should not include a function definition https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setparams

Comment: I am using react-navigation version 5. The most recent one

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a param with a function:

```
props.navigation.setParams({
    visibility:handleVisibility // <-- handleVisibility is a function
})
```

I think it should be:

```
props.navigation.setParams({
    visibility:menuVisible // <-- menuVisible insted
})
```

Comment: I am passing the function because in my navigationOptions I have a button and for the onPress of that button I am trying to trigger a function that changes the state that is why I am not passing the value but the function as a workaround

Comment: Well, try not doing a "workaround", i'm sure there is a good method of doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried different ways but so far I have found a good one.